# how to get .bak extension while creating backup in 3 tier project

Tags: c#

while click the backup btn it opened a savefiledialog box but i couldnt find .bak extension at save as type
code:
private void backupdb_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Visible = false;

```
        DataSet ds = SqlGetData.GetData1("select srvname  from sysservers  where srvproduct='SQL Server'");

        for (int m = 0; m < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; m++)
        {
            cbserver.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][m].ToString());
        }
    }
```

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbdb.Items.Clear();
            DataSet ds = SqlGetData.GetData1("select name from sysdatabases");
            for (int m = 0; m < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; m++)
            {
                cbdb.Items.Add((ds.Tables[0].Rows[m][0].ToString()).ToString());
            }
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        blank("backup");


    }

    public void blank(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbserver.Text) | string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbdb.Text))
        {

            label4.Visible = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Server Name & Database can not be Blank");
            return;

        }
        else
        {
            if (str == "backup")
            {
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = cbdb.Text;
                saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                string s = null;
                s = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.bak";
                query("Backup database " + cbdb.Text + " to disk='" + s + "'");

                label4.Visible = true;
                label4.Text = "Database BackUp has been created successful";



            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line to set the filter to be before the dialog is displayed

```
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.bak"
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I have done as you said. The file also saved in the particular section but I didn't get any .bak file in saved location. What could be the solution for this? Please help me out from this problem?

Comment: Sorry I thought your problem was why was there no "Save as" type listed  for .bak listed in the dialog. Can you clarify the problem?  You don't seem to have any code for actually saving/creating a file..

Comment: I want to save the sql db backup  file in the local drive. I got the message as well saying "Database successfully saved." But still I haven't get the file in my local drive.

Comment: I take it the Backup database query executes without error? Also if the db is on a different server, the path would have to be available on that server. For example, if you specify c:\backups as the path, it will save to that path, on the server, not where your app is running from.